# Referencing in style.css to sdk definition e.g. color.dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Having a polymer project using the material color definitions in `import 'package:polymer_elements/color.dart';` The references to css styling e.g. `var(--paper-green-300);` works ok, when they are placed in the `<style></style>` section for the element, but when I move this to the style.css, they aren't found. I have tried with different combinations of include in index.html and index.dart. E.g. in index.html at `<head>` section `<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/color.html">` but doesn't seems to do the trick. Anyone who have experience with similar issues?

Of course not a high prio project killer, simple to use the hard coded values or leave the definitions in the `<style>` section for every element. But this way things will be more tidy.

Environment

```
 Dart version 1.14.0
 WebStorm 11.0.3

From pubspec.yaml:
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.9.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.15
  web_components: ^0.12.0
  polymer_elements: 1.0.0-rc.8
  browser: ^0.10.0
  reflectable: ^0.5.0
  polymer_interop: ^1.0.0-rc.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS variables in Polymer only work in `<style is="custom-style">` and therefore not in `.css` files.

`is="custom-style"` is implicit for style tags within Polymer elements and can and should be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very useful. In plain polymer this seemed to addressed by something called Style modules  [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-modules). But seemes to be ignored in my environment. So I stick with the old solution.

Comment: Style modules should definitely work, but also only with inline styles.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Ok, I will give that one more try, maybe in minimal test project.